# Does self-reference in the constructor counts as "escaping"?

Tags: java, constructor

Reading [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp03304/) about JSR-133, it says:

> all of the writes to final fields (and to variables reachable
>   indirectly through those final fields) become "frozen," ...
>
> If an object's reference is not allowed to escape during construction,
>   then once a constructor has completed and a thread publishes a
>   reference to an object, that object's final fields are guaranteed to
>   be visible ...
>
> The one caveat with initialization safety is that the object's
>   reference must not "escape" its constructor -- the constructor should
>   not publish, directly or indirectly, a reference to the object being
>   constructed.

My question is about what is considered escaping. More specifically, I want to know if this (somewhat artificial and strange) code results in a safely-publishable Child object:

```
class Parent {
    /** NOT final. */
    private int answer;

    public int getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(final int _answer) {
        answer = _answer;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    private final Object self;

    public Child() {
        super.setAnswer(42);
        self = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAnswer(final int _answer) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

1. Firstly, while Parent is clearly mutable, Child is "effectively immutable", since the parent setter that would allow mutability is not reachable anymore.
2. The reference to "this" in the constructor is not visible to anyone (not getter, and not passed to any other object). So, does this count as "escaping"?
3. But the object as a whole is being referenced by a final field (self), and so in theory, it's whole content should then be "frozen". OTOH, the final field is itself not reachable, so maybe it doesn't count; I could very well imagine the JIT just completely optimizing it away.
4. If "self" was made accessible through a getter, but the getter is not called in the constructor, does it then count as escaping (assuming it didn't before)? This would prevent the JIT from optimizing it away, so that it must then "count", maybe?

So, is Child "safely-publishable", and if not, why, and would a getter for "self" change the answer?

In case the purpose of the question isn't clear, I think that if this works, it would allow one to easily make a mutable class "safely-publishable", by just extending it as shown above.

Comment: Read relevant paragraph:https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0618/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *may* be misunderstanding the meaning of escaping. The point is that the value of `this` must not reach any code foreign to the constructor. I think a few examples would explain it better:

- setting a private field to `this` doesn't count as escaping;
- calling a private method, which in turn doesn't call any further methods, and doesn't assign `this` to a foreign object's variable, doesn't count as escaping;
- calling a public, overridable method belonging to `this` *does* count as escaping unless the class is `final`. Therefore your code lets `this` escape when you call `setAnswer`, not when you assign `this` to `self`. Why? Because a subclass may override this method and publish `this` to any foreign code.

A note on your reasoning about `self`: `self` is reachable from `this` and this doesn't depend on the fact that a foreign caller cannot get its value. It is enough that a method may internally dereference it. Anyway, the rules about freezing do not take into account the access level of variables. For example, everything is reachable via reflection.

Comment: Would a reference be regarded as "escaping", for purposes of threading semantics, if there is no plausible execution sequence via which *another thread* could see it prior to its being stored into a `final` field?

Comment: I don't remember that's how the JLS defines it, but that's what the rules amount to, yes.

Comment: OK. You have found a flaw in my example; the call to Parent.setAnswer(). While I am generally aware that calling overridable methods in constructors is a big nono, I had not thought about that in this case (nor would I have ever counted it as "escaping this"!). Sill, your answer leaves me wanting; had I not called setAnswer(), say, if answer was protected instead, and I had set it directly, would Child then be safely publishable? Without "self", it would not, but I'm still not sure if "self" here helps at all.

Comment: Well, it clearly follows from the definitions you took note of that with `self` you are safe. The end result does strike one as somehow off---why would we need such a silly technicality to achieve this?

Comment: Given a pre-existing, mutable, type that we want to "not change after construction" and publish safely, this could allow it. OTOH, of course, the much cleaner and obvious solution would be to create a simple "Holder" with a final ref to the mutable object, and return the holder instead. Basically, this just saves one small allocation, but mostly, I was just curious.