# Does the this reference escape the constructor even on the last line?

Tags: java, thread-safety

after reading "java concurrency in practice", in paragraph 3.4, it says

"
An object is immutable if:
• Its state cannot be modified after construction; and.
• All its fields are final; and.
• It is properly constructed (**the this reference does not escape during
construction**).
"

And now I have a class:

```
class A {
  private final static ConcurrentMap<String, A> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
  private final code;
  private final name;

  A(String code, String name) {
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    cache.put(code, this); // does this escaped? and make immutable A not thread safe anymore?
  }

 public static A getA(String code) {
    return cache.get(code);
 }

}
```

and the below link seems helpful, but I am still confused.
link:
[Does self-reference in the constructor counts as "escaping"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555580/does-self-reference-in-the-constructor-counts-as-escaping)

summary: **in the above case, in the constructor, does "this" escape? and is the immutable A instance still thread safe?**

moreover, **if I move cache variable into another class, what will happen?**

Comment: If `cache` held a reference to an ordinary `HashMap` instead of a `ConcurrentHashMap`, then the answer would be a definite yes.  I'm assuming there must be some other code somewhere that calls `A.cache.get(...)`. (What would be the point of putting associations into a map if you're never going to look them up?) If that code ran in one thread while a different thread constructed a new `A` instance, the lack of any synchronization could allow the second thread to get a reference to the new instance before it was able to see the values assigned to `code` and `name`.

Comment: Using a `ConcurrentHashMap` effectively synchronizes the threads so that the second thread _must_ see the assignments that happened before the `put(...)` call if it is able to get the object reference from a `get(...)` call. But _I don't know_ whether that oficially counts as "safe publication."

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks for the comment ! yes, the cache can be accessed by some other code which may run in any thread. And I changed the code to make this clear

Comment: There would be no question if you used a factory method for A and moved the insertion into the cache to the factory.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I totally agree with you! But I am still curious and confused about this case.

Answer (score 0):

Technically the this reference **does** escape the constructor as it is passed to the cache **before** the constructor returns. That is, the cache receives a reference to an instance of `A` that is not yet fully initialised. Anyone accessing that instance concurrently through this cache will be able to observe this instance that is yet to be fully initialised. Since `cache.put` is the last line in the constructor this does likely not matter in practice. But I'd better not count on it and it breaks as soon `A` is [subclassed](https://github.com/mtumilowicz/java-this-escaping-constructor#remark).